# Is there a hotkey for 'centre view to selected', without zooming?

Tags: shortcut

Is there a 'centre view to selected' hotkey? Not to cursor or to mouse. Like 'view selected', but without the zoom (and no workarounds please with 'select all' or 'origin').

Comment: If I understand you correctly it's the "," on the (German) numpad. I guess it's a dot in English speaking countries.

Comment: Numpad dot (or menu: View / View selected)

Comment: Both of these answers tell you how to center the view AND zoom in, the OP was asking for a similar function without zooming; I am after the same thing.